# POST[]ing Extra Values

Tags: php, arrays, variables, post, captcha

I am creating a custom captcha where random numbers are generated and you have to add them together etc. As of right now I am echo-ing these random numbers but now I need to pull them into a external file to test the sum against the input text. Can I add these to the POST[] array on form submission?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to have some way of keeping track of the numbers and retrieving them back later for verification. You could use session variables- put the numbers in at the time of the page load, and then again when the form is POST'd and check them against each other.

Also, keep in mind anything on the form or that is put in $_POST can be easily viewed by anyone attempting to fool this process. Putting them in session variables makes it much harder for someone to view the contents of what their numbers will be checked against.

Comment: Anything put in $_POST can be easily viewed, resubmitted and automated, and you should code your handler pages with this in mind.

Comment: Maybe this is a question for another topic, but how?I could understand with get and cookies but how can a hacker get into and view the POST array or get into the POST content? Also thanks for your help session worked!

Comment: A hacker can see the fields and values that are submitted through your form using easily available software tools, and then re POST them as he/she wishes. In your case, you want to store the solution to your test and show the values on the screen independent of each other.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be necessary to post the numbers back. Just store them in a session variable on the server (or even just store the desired answer) and compare that. There'd be no point in storing the individual numbers, since they'd be thrown away and new ones generated each time anyways - captcha images/tests should never be reused.

Comment: How would I go about testing the numbers captcha along with the rest of the form without posting them to another file? The session variable is a good idea i might use that.