# PHP Hackers and the POST array

Tags: session, post, spam

I was told that it was easy but people to view the contents inside the $_POST[] array, is it really that easy? How do hackers do this and how do I prevent it? Should I start storing more items in the SESSION[] array instead?

[POST[]ing Extra Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835151/posting-extra-values)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The POST array is populated entirely by data transmitted from the client and everything inside it should be suspect. So don't take a number out of a postback request and set someone's account balance to it.

Also, "POST" is just a type of HTTP request, which means it's sent in plain text. Don't ask clients to send you login passwords over POST unless you wrap the HTTP stream with SSL (use https:// and configure your webserver properly) because you don't control the network between the client and your server. Major websites often don't do this (for performance reasons) but all online banks have done this for at least 10 years.

Comment: If needed though can't I use some kind of PHP encrypt function? such as md5?

Comment: @Howdy What you're saying is possible but almost certainly not in the way you think. See the other answer I just added (not enough characters in this comment box).

Answer (score 1):

Think that POST data are sended from the browser with the HTTP request in plain text.

People that can snif your network or execute a Man in the Midle hack, can view this.

With a firefox extension like Tamper Data, the user can change the POST data before sending it to the server.

Never thrust POST data, always validate it in the server side.

Answer (score 0):

From my comment on your earlier question:

A hacker can see the fields and values that are submitted through your form using easily available software tools, and then re POST them as he/she wishes.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding MD5:

md5 isn't an encryption algorithm, it's a hashing algorithm. It'll turn any string into a 16-byte hash. In theory:

1. If you have two objects, a and b, and md5(a) == md5(b), then a == b
2. If you have md5(a) you can't figure out a.

These are the implicit assumptions when working with hashes, although they're never actually true - number one is clearly not true because if you hash 2^16 + 1 different strings then by the Pigeonhole Principle there must be two different strings with the same hash. The second one is also obviously not true because an attacker can search the range of md5 values for the hash, although for modern cryptographic-secure hashes (not md5) this is infeasible.

Getting to your question, you could just ask the client for the md5 hash of the user's password (you'd need client side javascript to calculate this) but that's a terrible idea. If all you expect from the user is the md5 of her password, then that's all an attacker needs to know, and you're sending it in plain text. What you could do is send the client a *nonce*. This is like a challenge. For the client to prove she knows her password, she can send you a hash of the nonce and her password concatenated. The idea is that any attacker can't answer the challenge becuase he only knows the nonce, and after the nonce-password hash is transmitted it's too late for him because you've already received it and aren't expecting an answer to that nonce again. Property 2 ensures that he can't extract the password from the hash.

This is vulnerable to the attacker stealing the challenge response and getting it to you before the client does. You can have a lot of fun making up a whole cryptosystem with multi-round communication (counter-intuitively it's actually possible to send hashes back and forth and securely authenticate) but soon you're just implementing HTTPS which someone else has already done for you :)

Comment: hahaha it sounds like I still have a lot to learn. I'll have to look into nonce and play around with it. Great response!